# How to get "Date Difference" between a field of dates and a specified date?

Tags: r, date, type-conversion, datediff

```
Date.Trans 
20150623
20150613
20150616
20150611
20150625
```

Hi,

I want to calculate the Date diifference between Date.Trans and 07/07/2015 in the dataset named "boo" (the differences in days). I am quite new to R and I am finding it difficult to convert the Date.Trans string into a date and then calculate the difference in number of days.

this is what i have tried so far:

```
 strptime(boo$Date.Trans, "%y%m%d")
```

does not convert them.

```
 boo$days <- as.Date(boo$Date.Trans, "%Y%m%d")
```

> Error in charToDate(x) : 
>     character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Please help

Comment: Try `as.Date(as.character(boo$Date.Trans), "%Y%m%d")`

Comment: You just need a capital Y "%Y" in your first attempt.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you posted suggests that your `Date.Trans` column is of numeric type. If it was of character or factor type, then the `as.Date()` call would work. For a numeric type, you can achieve the requirement by coercing to character first:

```
boo <- data.frame(Date.Trans=c(20150623,20150613,20150616,20150611,20150625));
as.Date(boo$Date.Trans,'%Y%m%d');
## Error in charToDate(x) :
##   character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
boo$days <- as.Date('2015-07-07') - as.Date(as.character(boo$Date.Trans),'%Y%m%d');
boo;
##   Date.Trans    days
## 1   20150623 14 days
## 2   20150613 24 days
## 3   20150616 21 days
## 4   20150611 26 days
## 5   20150625 12 days
sapply(boo,class);
## Date.Trans       days
##  "numeric" "difftime"
```

In general, you should try to coerce to appropriate data types from the earliest possible moment; that will help prevent these kinds of difficulties. For example, if defining `boo` inline, you could do this:

```
boo <- data.frame(Date.Trans=as.Date(c('2015-06-23','2015-06-13','2015-06-16','2015-06-11','2015-06-25')));
boo;
##   Date.Trans
## 1 2015-06-23
## 2 2015-06-13
## 3 2015-06-16
## 4 2015-06-11
## 5 2015-06-25
class(boo$Date.Trans);
## [1] "Date"
```

Or, if it's too late, for example if you read in the data from a file, then you can fix it up afterward:

```
boo$Date.Trans <- as.Date(as.character(boo$Date.Trans),'%Y%m%d');
boo;
##   Date.Trans
## 1 2015-06-23
## 2 2015-06-13
## 3 2015-06-16
## 4 2015-06-11
## 5 2015-06-25
class(boo$Date.Trans);
## [1] "Date"
```

Comment: The `as.character(` is seen somewhere :-)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt respond @bgoldst. it works perfectly and you have saved a lot of my time. Thanks again.